# how to response.write bytearray?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is not working:

```
byte[] tgtBytes = ...

Response.Write(tgtBytes);
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You're probably looking for:

```
Response.BinaryWrite(tgtBytes);
```

MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524318.aspx).

Comment: I never understood non-alphabetic ordering of clearly related functions..  It makes obvious things like this much more difficult to track down.

Comment: Although when you're working in Visual Studio if you type Response.Write it will also bring up BinaryWrite in the autocomplete list. Or maybe that's just because I use resharper?

Comment: That's a new feature in Visual Studio 2010. Previous versions only did auto-complete on the start of member names, not the contents of member names.

Comment: @AndrewBarrett: Yes, you are right, but for example in VS 2013, if you have already the Write method in your code, and you press Ctrl + Space to bring up the method names using autocomplete, you see all the method names in alphabetical order around the Write method, and not the method names containing Write.

Answer (score 19):

```
Response.OutputStream.Write(tgtBytes, 0, tgtBytes.Length);
```

Comment: This actually works out better, if you want to use the Response stream if the file is huge. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output hex values

```
byte[] tgtBytes = ...
foreach (byte b in tgtBytes)
    Response.Write("{0:2x}", b);
```

Or do you want to do;

```
Response.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(tgtBytes));
```

To convert the bytes to ASCII text and output a string.